# Linux batch copy files into directories based on filename pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a list of almost 500 pdf files with the following filename structure:

```
XXXX-YYYY-MM-DD.pdf
```

where `XXXX` is a variable lenght numeric code (**1 to 4 digits**) always delimitated by "-", for example:

```
51-2016-08-22.pdf
776-2016-08-22.pdf
3881-2016-08-22.pdf
4-2016-08-22.pdf
2860-2016-08-22.pdf
```

The goal is to copy each file into its own directory, naming the directories like the pattern (ie: file 776-2016-08-22.pdf goes to directory 776). How can I use awk or sed to delimitate the variable lenght field?

Here's my code:

```
for f in *.pdf

    do
        FOLDERNAME=`echo $f| awk (awk or sed missing code here)`
        mkdir /my/dir/structure/$FOLDERNAME
        cp $f /my/dir/structure/$FOLDERNAME/
    done
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Learn to use shell parameter expansion operators instead of piping to programs: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: `sed s/-.*//` will remove everything starting from the first `-`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
for f in *.pdf; do
    d="${f%%-*}"
    mkdir -p "$d" && cp "$f" "$d"
done
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for your post. Is the same syntax valid also to extract a portion of the filename, or shall I use sed for that purpose? For example: if I had to create also a subfolder using the year (YYYY) as folder name, which syntax would  you recommend?

Comment: For creating directories using year part I suggest using BASH regex like this: **`for f in *.pdf; do [[ $f =~ ^[^-]+-([0-9]{4})- ]] && echo mkdir -p "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; echo cp "$f" "$d"; done`**

Answer (score 1):

As rightly pointed out by [ed-morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton), This is **NOT** recommended solution as it fails in many cases. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/39089589/3834860

Keeping this answer for reference.

`awk -F '-'` to specify delimiter and `'{print $1}'` for first element before delimiter.

```
for f in *.pdf

do
    FOLDERNAME=`echo $f| awk -F '-' '{print $1}'`
    mkdir /my/dir/structure/$FOLDERNAME
    cp $f /my/dir/structure/$FOLDERNAME/
done
```

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for your comments.